# E3372 Does Not Work in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, compatibility, dongle

I have signed another Section of a Contract with a Telecommunication Operator for an Internet Mobile Modem 4G E3372 Dongle produced by the Huawei Technologies Corporation Limited based in Bantian, Longgang District, Shenzhen, 518129, People's Republic of China.

The Huawei Corporation does not offer support for any kind of Dongle on its [Support Web-Page](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/mobile-broadband/dongles/).

The Cardboard Box of the Device specifies that the Compatible Operating System List does not include the Microsoft Windows 10 Operating System.

The Official Huawei [Specification Web-Page](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-broadband/e3372/specs/) of the E3372 Dongle also does not list the Microsoft Windows 10 Operating System among the Supported Operating Systems.

The Cardboard Box of the Device specifies that the Interface Type is USB 2.0 High Speed.

The ASUS [machine](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X551MA/specifications/) is endowed with an USB 2.0 Port and with an USB 3.0 Port.

All these being said, nothing is happening when I am inserting the Dongle in either USB Port.

I have already tested this Issue on two Machines running the Microsoft Windows 10 Operating System. On the other Machine, I have selected running the `AutoRun.EXE` Executable Binary File upon the Insertion of the Dongle in an USB 2.0 Port, but nothing has been run afterwards.

Attempting to run various Third-Party Device Drivers (produced by the Lenovo Corporation, for instance) using the Microsoft Windows 8 Compatibility Mode has not solved this Issue so far.

Amazingly enough, the Telecommunication Operator has allegedly not encountered this Issue so far and they are waiting for my Status Report in order to tell them whether I have been able to solve the issue on my own or not.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

E3372 does not work in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. It does work in older Windows 10 versions. Huawei support told me yesterday that Microsoft is working on a windows update to adress the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like to install additional software. Here is a workaound I just found: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/modem-dongle-not-working-on-windows-10-fall/913eaf82-d0aa-4a86-bd1d-2a146adc2924?auth=1

Comment: The fact it works on a Windows 8 machine does not really help if you are running Windows 10.

Answer (score -3):

We have also stumbled on this problem and there is a workaround that can be found [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/modem-dongle-not-working-on-windows-10-fall/913eaf82-d0aa-4a86-bd1d-2a146adc2924?auth=1).

> "Hey,
>
> I solved the problem by realizing that the modem isn't able to find
>   itself an I.P. address, so you have to do it yourself in the *Windows*
>   options:
>
> 1. Go to the *Control Panel*, search for the *Control Panel*.
> 2. Navigate to *Network and Internet* -> *Network and Sharing Center*
> 3. On the right sidebar, you will see *Change adapter settings*, go there.
> 4. There you will see a few devices, open the one that has a greyed text: *Remote N.D.I.S. based Internet Sharing Device* (some text
>      probably cut out).
> 5. *Properties* -> Select *Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)* by clicking on it -> *Properties*.
> 6. Click on *Use the following I.P. address:* and fill in these values:
>
>    I.P. address: 192.168.1.100
>
>    Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
>
>    Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
>
>    These D.N.S. servers are Google Public D.N.S.'s, you can use your
>      preferred one if you want.
>
>    Preferred D.N.S. server: 8.8.8.8
>
>    Alternate D.N.S. server: 8.8.4.4
>
>    And check the tick box that says *Validate settings upon exit*.
> 7. Click OK and it should work wonders after this."

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Changing those settings should take no more than a couple of minutes.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai I would be surprised if there is an automated way of doing what you want.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Yes, but automating it requires cooperation between the dongle manufacturer's software and MS. If one of those is missing you are stuck.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Let's not. I don't have any more to add :)